# Is Arizona's sheriff Joe Arpaio being considered for Secretary of Homeland Security?

Tags: politics

I found an [article](http://www.rightwingwatch.org/post/trump-transition-team-floats-extremist-sheriffs-joe-arpaio-and-david-clarke-for-homeland-security/) from RightWingWatch claiming that the former Maricopa County Sheriff Joe Arpaio is being considered by Trump's administration for the Secretary of the Department of Homeland Security (along with Sheriff David Clarke of Wisconsin).

> Donald Trump’s transition team is reportedly considering Milwaukee County, Wisconsin, Sheriff David Clarke and outgoing Maricopa County, Arizona, **Sheriff Joe Arpaio** as possible nominees to head up the Department of Homeland Security.

The article uses [this](http://www.politico.com/story/2016/11/who-is-in-president-trump-cabinet-231071) Politico article as a source, which makes absolutely no mention of Joe Arpaio, only David Clarke, a Milwaukee sheriff. (see subheading of article titled "Homeland Security secretary")

Lots of other news sources have taken this and run with it, including countless AZ-local news sites ([KTAR Radio](http://ktar.com/story/1355142/maricopa-county-sheriff-joe-arpaio-open-working-donald-trump/), [12 News](http://www.12news.com/news/politics/arpaios-legal-battle-could-disappear-thanks-to-trump/350765357), [azfamily](http://www.azfamily.com/story/33677857/secretary-of-homeland-security-joe-arpaio)) and the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/wp/2016/11/11/trump-homeland-security-candidates-include-gop-lawmakers-and-less-likely-a-sheriff/).

I also found an Arizona-local [source from AZCentral](http://www.azcentral.com/story/news/politics/politicalinsider/2016/11/11/sb1070-author-kris-kobach-joins-donald-trump-immigration-transition-team/93628108/) that explicitly states:

> A name straight out of Arizona's controversial immigration past has popped up on President-elect Donald Trump's transition team.
>
> It's **not** former Gov. Jan Brewer or outgoing **Maricopa County Sheriff Joe Arpaio** ...[sic] at least not yet.

...except the transition team is different from Homeland Security, so it's unclear whether this excludes the possibility.

EDIT: I found an article from [ABC News](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/trump-cabinet/story?id=43478002) that has a list of potential cabinet members, but I can't figure out whether this is speculation or verifiable statements.

Comment: Side question about quoting etiquette: is it proper form to indicate when an ellipsis is included in the original text (as opposed to being used to omit unnecessary info), and have I done it correctly in the second blockquote?

Comment: [sic] usually indicates an outright mistake, whereas you've used it for simply subpar orthography. But I don't think that's necessarily an error.

Comment: "Considering" is a very broad term, and these deliberations tend to be confidential. What evidence would convince you (short of an actual appointment) either way?

Comment: There's really no way for this to be ascertained beyond guesswork